# AWS Create Listener from Console - All target groups are greyed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-nlb

I have a Network Load Balancer (NLB) running in my VPC. I am trying to create a listener for my NLB from the console. The corresponding EC2 instance (that corresponding to my target group) and its listener require SSL. I am creating a listener to use protocol TLS on port 443. When I attempt to assign my  targeting group the listener I am attempting to create, I need to be able to forward traffic to my targeting group. The console provides the mechanism as shown below:

[image]

Under "Forward to..." I can see my targeting group, however all the targeting groups under the pull-down are greyed out. Therefore I cannot select it and complete my listener.

I have tried every type of ALPN Policy, and have even tried HTTP/8080 (just as a sanity check). Regardless of what I do, none of the targeting groups in the Forward TO pull-down can be selected. All the related resources (NLB, EC2 of targeting group and its listener, and the targeting group itself) are running/created, etc.

I have never created an NLB before, so not sure what might ve going on here. I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show setup of your TG that you want to use?

Comment: @Marcin I cannot show much detail for security reasons. What types of details would be useful?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49352582/13126651

Comment: @JatinMehrotra thanks for pointing that out. However, that guy appeared to just be mismatching protocol/port of his TG to his load balancer. For me, it makes no difference what I specify for protocol/port, all TGs are greyed-out. I am wondering whether it might be that my NLB requires an IAM role that allows to forward to the TG? Perhaps I just need to figure out how to add that role to my NLB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I figured it out. This is probably AWS 101, but it was not obvious to me (kind of a AWS novice). The problem for me was that my TG was already associated with a listener. Why was it already associated with a listener? Because I had earlier set up the TG for a different (HTTP) listener and forgot to detach it from that listener. As soon as I did that, the TG was selectable in the above pull-down.

But it makes perfect sense it hindsight. A targeting group can only be associated with a single listener.